# Blazor calling JSInterop script that builds UI fails to render correctly

Tags: javascript, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-jsinterop, mapkit-js

I'm trying to get this to work as per [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-libraries-that-render-ui).

The below script code works perfectly in an existing React app and I'm trying to port the app to Blazor. The script loads and inits - and I can see the Iframe being correctly loaded into the browser DOM. However the script (Apple's mapkit.js script) errors out with `Attempted to assign to readonly property` in the `migrateStateTo` function, trying to set `t.tint = this.node.tint`.

**MapkitHelper.js**

```
import "https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js";

export function initialiseMapkit(token, element) {
  // this call seems to work
  mapkit.init({
    authorizationCallback: function(done) {
      done(token)
    }  
  })
  // from here on things seem to go south no matter what I do
  var map = new mapkit.Map(element)
}
```

**MapkitRenderer.razor**

```
@implements IAsyncDisposable
@inject IJSRuntime JS

<div @ref="mapkitElement"></div>

@code {
  public string? token = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MAPKIT_JS_TOKEN");

  private ElementReference mapkitElement;
  private IJSObjectReference? mapModule;

  protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender) {
    if (firstRender) {
      mapModule = await JS.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./MapkitHelper.js");
      await mapModule.InvokeVoidAsync("initialiseMapkit", token, mapkitElement);
    }
  }

  async ValueTask IAsyncDisposable.DisposeAsync() {
    if (mapModule is not null) {
      await mapModule.DisposeAsync();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you figure this one out? Seeing the same error with similar setup

Comment: Nevermind, I did, in my case I was importing my library twice, redefining the same name for it twice

Comment: @robuk did you ever get this working. if yes, please provide sample code.

Comment: @thomasstephn could you share a working example?

Comment: @BarryMSIH to be honest I abandoned this and Blazor completely - the project relied on a number of external modules and trying to get these (or equivalents/replacements) to work with Blazor just turned into an exercise in futility, especially as C#/JS/TS is not really my day job.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem because I loaded mapkit.js as a module.

```
import "https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js";
```

Loading mapkit.js as a module results in an exception because mapkit.js is not compatible with JavaScript's strict mode. You must instead load mapkit.js in sloppy mode.

```
<script src="https://cdn.apple-mapkit.com/mk/5.x.x/mapkit.js"></script>
```

Based on https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/706389